# why i can't import my grid view with custom adapter into a fragment?

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, custom-adapter

what i am trying to do is to view a grid view with custom adapter into fragment because i want to use a view pager with a swipe filter .. and here is my code :

```
 public class KitchenBlinds extends Fragment {
        public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.kit_1, R.drawable.kit_2,
                R.drawable.kit_3, R.drawable.kit_4,
                R.drawable.kit_5, R.drawable.kit_6,
                R.drawable.kit_7, R.drawable.kit_8,
                R.drawable.kit_9, R.drawable.kit_10,
                R.drawable.kit_11, R.drawable.kit_12,
                R.drawable.kit_13, R.drawable.kit_14,
                R.drawable.kit_15
        };
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_kitchen_blinds, container, false);

            return view;




        GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
          try{
            // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
                gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), mThumbIds)); 
          } catch (OutOfMemoryError E) { 
            E.printStackTrace();
        }


            /**
             * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
             * */
            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                    Intent i = new Intent(KitchenBlinds.this, FullImageActivity2.class);
                    // passing array index
                     i.putExtra("id", mThumbIds[position]);
                        Log.d("ID", "" + mThumbIds[position]);
                         startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }




        }
```

but i keep see an error in this line :

```
 GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
```

and also in this one :

```
  Intent i = new Intent(KitchenBlinds.this, FullImageActivity2.class);
```

can you help me to use a grid view into fragment please???

and this is my kitchen_blinds_layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>
```

Comment: post your `activity_kitchen_blinds.xml`

Comment: ok i will post it now

Comment: Whether it worked or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Major error is return view . Do like this

```
public class KitchenBlinds extends Fragment {
            public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                    R.drawable.kit_1, R.drawable.kit_2,
                    R.drawable.kit_3, R.drawable.kit_4,
                    R.drawable.kit_5, R.drawable.kit_6,
                    R.drawable.kit_7, R.drawable.kit_8,
                    R.drawable.kit_9, R.drawable.kit_10,
                    R.drawable.kit_11, R.drawable.kit_12,
                    R.drawable.kit_13, R.drawable.kit_14,
                    R.drawable.kit_15
            };
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_kitchen_blinds, container, false);

                GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
              try{
                // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
                    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), mThumbIds)); 
              } catch (OutOfMemoryError E) { 
                E.printStackTrace();
            }


                /**
                 * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
                 * */
                gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {

                        // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                        Intent i = new Intent(KitchenBlinds.this, FullImageActivity2.class);
                        // passing array index
                         i.putExtra("id", mThumbIds[position]);
                            Log.d("ID", "" + mThumbIds[position]);
                             startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }

      return view;


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of

```
 Intent i = new Intent(KitchenBlinds.this, FullImageActivity2.class);
```

is a `Context`, but `KitchenBlinds` is a Fragment. You shoud change it with `getActivity()`

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FullImageActivity2.class);
```

Also, you are returning too earlier. The return statements should be the last line of code inside your `onCreateView` otherwise you will get a compile time error.

Move `return view` at the end of `onCreateView`

Answer (score 1):

The first error you are getting is because you have not imported your grid-view in your project so first import it by pressing Ctrl + Shift + o (in eclipse).

The second error that you have in below line

```
Intent i = new Intent(KitchenBlinds.this, FullImageActivity2.class);
```

is wrong. Since you are using fragment you have to use it like this.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent((MainActivity) getActivity(),FullImageActivity2.class);
                    // passing array index
                     myIntent .putExtra("id", mThumbIds[position]);
                        Log.d("ID", "" + mThumbIds[position]);
                         getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
```

and also you forget to return your view.

so basically your full code will loo something like this.

```
public class KitchenBlinds extends Fragment {
        public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.kit_1, R.drawable.kit_2,
                R.drawable.kit_3, R.drawable.kit_4,
                R.drawable.kit_5, R.drawable.kit_6,
                R.drawable.kit_7, R.drawable.kit_8,
                R.drawable.kit_9, R.drawable.kit_10,
                R.drawable.kit_11, R.drawable.kit_12,
                R.drawable.kit_13, R.drawable.kit_14,
                R.drawable.kit_15
        };
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_kitchen_blinds, container, false);

        GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
          try{
            // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
                gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), mThumbIds)); 
          } catch (OutOfMemoryError E) { 
            E.printStackTrace();
        }


            /**
             * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
             * */
             gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent((MainActivity) getActivity(),FullImageActivity2.class);
                    // passing array index
                     myIntent .putExtra("id", mThumbIds[position]);
                        Log.d("ID", "" + mThumbIds[position]);
                         getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
               return view;
        }
        }
```

Comment: ok .. i have returned the view but still i have an error on this line : GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

Comment: I think you have not imported your gridview, if you are using eclipse try pressing Ctrl + Shift + o.

Answer (score 0):

write `return view;` in the end of the onCreateView function

also change

```
Intent i = new Intent(KitchenBlinds.this, FullImageActivity2.class);
```

to

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FullImageActivity2.class);
```

onCreateView:

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_kitchen_blinds, container, false);

        GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
          try{
            // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
                gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), mThumbIds)); 
          } catch (OutOfMemoryError E) { 
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

            /**
             * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
             * */
            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                    Intent i = new Intent(KitchenBlinds.this, FullImageActivity2.class);
                    // passing array index
                     i.putExtra("id", mThumbIds[position]);
                        Log.d("ID", "" + mThumbIds[position]);
                         startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            return view;//return here

        }
```